# Why would a .tex file compile with PDFLatex but not simpdftex?

Tags: pdftex

I have been trying to compile the [acmart](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart) samples in a manner that I am familiar.  Instead of using PDFLatex and in their Makefile example, I am trying to compile the source using TeX + DVI due to the fact that I want the intermediate files (I have a bunch of TiKz rendering).  When I type:

```
pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 sample-manuscript.tex
```

Everyone is fine and well.  When I type:

```
simpdftex latex --maxpfb --extratexopts "-file-line-error -synctex=1" --distiller ps2pdf14 sample-manuscript.tex
```

I get a stack error, Error: /undefined in XC@ACMRed, and a whole bunch of chaos.

Is there any reason that a .tex file would compile with pdflatex and not the TeX+DVI path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the fact that the class defines some colors using the `cmyk` model.

If I pass the `rgb` option to `xcolor`, compilation with `simpdftex` is successful. Do

```
\documentclass[manuscript, review, screen, rgb]{acmart}
```

or add `\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}` before the `\documentclass` line.

The option forces `xcolor` to do conversion to RGB for every defined color, whatever model the definition uses.

A minimal file that exhibits the same problem, but not if we do `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor[named]{ACMRed}{cmyk}{0,0.90,0.86,0}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{ACMRed}{XYZ}

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer who, in chat, set my attention to the `prologue` option. So, instead of `rgb`, a better solution is to do

```
\documentclass[manuscript, review, screen, prologue]{acmart}
```

I'll make an issue report to Boris.

Comment: It would have been nice if it threw some sort of error as it seems that is something that could be checked.   Thank you for solving this.

Comment: @bdegnan The error happens during the `ps2pdf` phase, so too late for LaTeX do issue meaningful errors.

Comment: @bdegnan There's even a better way.

Comment: https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/257